# Creating an instance of a class doesn't execute onCreate

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer

This may be pretty basic question, but I've been wrestling with it long enough.

I'm trying to create an instance of a class that handles android's magnetometer.
I've got the class set up, but now I need to put it to use.

Here is the class

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mMagnetometer;

@Override
public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();    // just to see if this really executes
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    myTextView.setText("done");

}

@Override
public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
}

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float magnetic_field = event.values[0];
    String m = Float.toString(magnetic_field);
                        // Update textview with values
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    myTextView.setText("done");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

}

Now I'm instantiating the class by having this in MainActivity onCreate()

```
SensorActivity mSensorActivity = new SensorActivity();
```

Nothing happens. If this doesn't run, I'll just drop the class since I already got something out with directly accessing the SensorManager and Sensor

Comment: `SensorActivity mSensorActivity = new SensorActivity();` is wrong. You should never do that. You only declare the activity in manifest file and have appropriate launch mode flags.

Comment: You should not get instance of activity that way